# ¿Como Modificar la fuente de una lista en android?

Tags: java, android

Lo que quiero hacer es que mi lista en mi app de android tenga una letra diferente con mas estilo, ya tengo las fuentes de tipo .ttf en la carpeta de assets y ya lo hice con un textview pero no eh podido implementarlo en una lista

Aquí tengo mi constructor de la clase de Java

```
Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    Typeface tf;

    public AyudarApp(Context context, int layoutResourceId,String FONT ) {
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), FONT);
    }
```

De esta manera asigno todo a mi constructor

```
    AyudarApp my_adapter = new AyudarApp(AyudarApp.this , R.layout.activity_ayudar ,"font/Cursive standard.ttf");
    mListView.setAdapter((ListAdapter) my_adapter);
```

El error esta en que al querer entrar en donde esta mi lista me marca que la aplicacion a dejado de funcionar y me saca de la app

Comment: Cuando te saca del OP te aparecerá un error en la consola. ¿Qué tipo de error te da? Aunque, sin embargo, supongo que el error que te estará dando es porque estás intentando castear un objeto `AyudarApp` con una clase `ListAdapter`.

Comment: David, esta pregunta puede considerarse demasiado amplia si no agregas el mensaje desplegado en el LogCat, lo que comentas puede ocurrir por una infinidad de causas!

Answer (score 0):

Para cargar una fuente desde Assets para ser usada en tu aplicación esta es la forma correcta:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "myfuente.ttf");
```

En tu aplicación, el problema el problema acerca de que se cierra la aplicación puede ocurrir por diversas causas, incluyendo las que no son relacionadas a el cargado de la fuente.

Lo que pudiera evitar el problema al cargar la fuente es lo siguiente,

- Asegura tener un contexto, la variable `context` no tenga valor null.
- La variable `FONT` debe contener un String que contiene un String con el nombre de la fuente (extensión .ttf).

:

```
tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), FONT);
```